# How do you show pop up under an item?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have this in a class:

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)

val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_password, null))
builder.setCancelable(true)

val dialog = builder.create()
dialog?.show()
```

It creates a pop up in the center of the screen and moves up when you tap on the edit text in the pop up.

[image]

I want the pop up to show below the button that is pressed and not move up when the keyboard comes up.

[image]

Comment: You can use Popup menu for exact location at the bottom, https://material.io/components/menus/android#dropdown-menus

Answer (score 1):

You can refrer this Java Code

```
   //Todo Custom PopUP
private void openCustomUserPopUp() {
    PopupWindow popupwindow_obj = popupDisplay();
    popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(mTollUser, -40, 18); // where u want show on view click event popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view, x, y);
}


//Todo Custom PopUP
public PopupWindow popupDisplay() {

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    // inflate your layout or dynamically add view
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu_custom_layout, null);

    mTxtPopupName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_popup_name);
    
    mTxtPopupName.setText(preferenceManager.getUSER_NAME());
    
    mTxtPopupName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(500);
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);

    return popupWindow;
}
```